# %d within print statement python

Tags: python

I encountered this in a function of a program and I don't understand how the %d can work inside a closed quote print statement.

```
print "%d squared is %d." % (n, squared)
```

The output when the argument of 10 (which is `n`) is passed is:
10 squared is 100

Comment: See Format Specifiers(https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: That's some very basic Python, look it up in the manual or the tutorial you use.

Comment: What is the issue you're having? `n` and `squared` are both number variables, which replace the `%d` in the string passed to print. (That's what the `%` in `... d." % (n, ...` is used for).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: The `%` operator is string formating - it has nothing to do with the `print` statement.

Comment: Please use `str.format` instead of the old style string formatting which is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The `"%"` operator is used to format a set of variables enclosed in a tuple (a fixed size list), together with a format string.

```
print ("%d squared is %d" % (10, 10*10))
```

The `%` operators in the string are replaced in order by the elements in the tuple.

`%d` is used for integers, where as `%s` is used for strings

Eg.

```
>>>name = "John"
>>>age = 23
>>>print "%s is %d years old." % (name, age)
John is 23 years old.
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am a programming newbie.  I did a google search btw.  I thought it needed to be enclosed in () to do the replacing action but I guess it doesn't.  You can delete this question if you want.. Thanks again for your explantion. Cheers